# MySQL - returning names of entities that do not have a match in another table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I've been searching for answers awhile on here, but I'm just ending up going in circles.

anyways, assuming I have two tables:

**Employee** with the attributes **first_name, last_name, middle_initial,** and **ESSN**

and

**dependents** with the attributes **essn, dependent_name** and  **relationship**

I want to simply list the names of all department managers who have no dependents.
The code i'm trying to use works if the != is set to =, and gives me the matching results.

What do I to pull up the results that do not match?

```
select employee.first_name, employee.middle_initial, employee.last_name
from employee join dependent on employee.essn = dependent.essn
where employee.essn != dependent.essn
group by employee.first_name;
```

i also attempted to use != with the ESSN of the department managers, but I ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved much easier:

```
select first_name from employee where essn not in (select essn from dependent);
```

Comment: b-e-a-utiful!  Thank you for helping out a novice such as myself!  Now, to familiarize myself with this not in function!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `left join where dependent.essn is null`

```
select employee.first_name, employee.middle_initial, employee.last_name
from employee 
left join dependent 
on employee.essn = dependent.essn
where dependent.essn is null
```

My bad..just noticed this is mysql.. I assume it would be the same as mssql